# AJAX set max in number (spinner) field from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, numbers, max

I am trying to set the "max" setting in a number input field.  I have successfully set the default value to my variable available_seats using:

```
<input type="number" min="" max="" step="1"  name="available_seats" id="available_seats"/>
```

and

```
$('input[name="available_seats"]').val(response.available_seats);
```

However, I am having a lot of trouble setting the min and max settings.  Here's what I've tried;

```
$('#available_seats').spinner('option', 'max', data.available_seats);
```

That doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: your tags are not going to help you. Should have jquery and or javascript.

Comment: This is not all of the code, I am using jQuery.  I have successfully been able to change the "value" setting in the input field using that first line. Now I am trying to figure out what I need to do to to get it to update the "max" value of the input field. And "spinner" came from some code I found somewhere... but I figured it should be something close to `$('input[name="available_seats"]').val('option', 'max', response.available_seats);` or similar... I'm just lost.

Comment: Is sinner a jQuery plugin? If you want to change the attributes, that you should be setting the attribute

Comment: Got it.  So `$('input[name="available_seats"]').attr('max', response.available_seats);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input has attributes so set the attributes.

```js
$("#available_seats")
    .attr("min", 10)
    .attr("max", 20)
    .val(15);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" min="" max="" step="1"  name="available_seats" id="available_seats"/>
```

Comment: Great, thank you.  Since I am using the variable available_seats, I got it to work with:  `$('input[name="available_seats"]').attr('max', response.available_seats);`